# Display SSRS Report in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services

I am trying to get a report from SQL Server Reporting Services to appear on a WPF application. The server has SQL Server 2014.

I added a ReportViewer to my XAML as I had seen in examples:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFReport.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="850">

    ...

    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="_reportViewer" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>

    ...

</Window>
```

The code I see everywhere to connect the ReportViewer to a report is like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _reportViewer.Load += ReportViewer_Load;
}

private void ReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!_isReportViewerLoaded)
    {
        _reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        _reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = 
            new Uri("http://{MyReportServer}/ReportServer/");
        _reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Reports/{MyReportName}.rdl";

        _reportViewer.RefreshReport();

        _isReportViewerLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

The report I am trying to access, however, appears to be accessed in a different way.

I can access it in a browser by going through a `ReportViewer.aspx` file:

```
http://{MyReportServer}/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f{MyReportName}
```

Is there a way to access my report in a ReportViewer?

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a few formats, this appears to work:

```
_reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
_reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://{MyReportServer}/ReportServer");
_reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/{MyReportName}";

_reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```